# Regex Advanced Capture

Tags: regex, capture

I am trying to retrieve a weapon classname from a string.

The string could look like:

```
econ/default_generated/weapon_m4a1_silencer_am_m4a1-s_alloy_orange_medium
```

And I would want:

```
weapon_m4a1_silencer
```

But the trick here is, Sometimes the classname could have either 2 or 3 instances of "_"

So a 2nd example would be:

```
econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_am_scales_bravo_medium
```

And would give me:

```
weapon_deagle
```

A pattern which could be used is that their is always 2 letters which are inside the _ that come after the classname, (In this case "*am*")

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit there appears to be cases where there is more _ instances than I thought.
Example: https://regex101.com/r/Cmup26/1 weapon_knife_m9_bayonet is not captured.

Comment: Use a positive lookahead that matches `_.._`

Comment: Does the string always begin with `weapon_`?  Wouldn't that be a better indicator than \_xx\_?

Comment: Yes, it always begins with weapon_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated - to get up until last _AA***_

`weapon(?:(?:_[^\W_]+)+(?=_[^\W_]{2}_)|(?:(?!_[^\W_]{2}_)_[^\W_]+)+)`

https://regex101.com/r/r6yORE/1

where `[^\W_]` is `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (substitute allowed letters)

Expanded

```
 weapon
 (?:                           # Cluster - requires a  _Segment
      (?: _ [^\W_]+ )+
      (?= _ [^\W_]{2} _ )           # Stop before last _AA_ (high priority)
   |                              # or,
      (?:                           # Stop before first _AA_ (low priority)
           (?! _ [^\W_]{2} _ )      #  (note- this is only place where 
           _  [^\W_]+               #   segments with NO trailing _AA_ 
      )+                            #   will match)
 )
```

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up, I thought it was fine but I was wrong.

You answer is fine, but I mistakenly thought there would only be 2 or 3 instances, I was wrong.. https://regex101.com/r/Cmup26/1

As you can see weapon_knife_m9_bayonet is not captured unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you so much, It is perfect now :)

Comment: Wouldn't `weapon.*?(?=_\w\w_)` be a lot simpler?

Comment: @Tezra - You mean instead of `_[^\W_][^\W_]_` ? Probably, except `_\w\w_` matches `____`. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: I mean as whole regex. Just start anchor on 'weapon' and then grab the minimal characters `.*?` up to first instance of `_XX_` (the `(?=_\w\w_)` end anchor). The `\w` can be replaced with whatever char-set is valid there. The OP said `_<char><char>_` is guaranteed to be there, so why allow a string to have no instance of that pattern in it?

Comment: @Tezra - You can try out other possibilities if you want. `.*?`,  grabs minimum up to _XX_, he wants the maximum, change it to `.*`.`why allow a string to have no instance of that` [\_XX\_] - What if there is none? It's my experience you don't throw away the baby with the bathwater. And that would be too easy then, either https://regex101.com/r/r6yORE/2 or https://regex101.com/r/r6yORE/3 But, both of these move away from a controlled match, especially the one with `.*`